# Processing audio files from s3 bucket for speech to text conversion in Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have files stored in an s3 bucket that are uploaded from Genysis Purecloud. They are customer calls saved as .opus files but can be converted to .wav files when using a download function in python. I am having problems processing these files using the Python libraries `boto3` and `speech_recognition`.

I need to be able to call the audio file (as variable f below) in the following script to firstly transform the audio into text and then run it through an NLP algorithm:

```
audio = f
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile(audio) as source:
    # listen for the data (load audio to memory)
    audio_data = r.record(source)
    #recognize (convert from speech to text)
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data)
    print(text)
```

I can use the get() function in boto3 to retrieve the object/file from s3:

```
s3_object = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket).Object('9d3be36b-6777-4b2a-8912-4dbfaaeea0ab/year=2022/month=11/day=10/hour=0/conversation_id=00d32818-16f5-4a6f-a97c-3db50ce9254f/36f1c0ce-d168-4df3-bae8-219bd5b59802.opus').get()
```

The problem is that the speech recognition library does not accept this as audio data as it is not reading the object as a file such as .wav .mp3 etc.

Any ideas on how I can pull the files from s3 so that they are in a format where I can process them?
Thanks

I have tried using the get() function in boto3.
I have also tried downloading the object onto my local drive. I managed to save this as a .wav file and when trying the process in the speech recognition library, get the follwing error:

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 485: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to transcode from opus to wav or mp3?

Comment: Is there a way to transcode this from the s3 object so I don't have to download to my local machine? Would this work with the binary .opus file?

Comment: os.system("ffmpeg -i \"{}\" -vn \"{}\"".format(file1,
                                                    file1[:-len(file_type_to_convert)] +
                                                    file_type_to_recognize))

Comment: You can [download](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html) the object from S3 to local disk, transcode to a supported format using FFMPEG or other, and then send the resulting wav/mp3 to your `sr.audio()` function. Also FYI Amazon's Transcribe supports opus natively, and Transcribe can transcribe an object that's in S3, so you wouldn't need to download or transcode the audio file.

Comment: ok thanks i'll look into using Amazon's Transcribe feature. For the download option as I have 100's of files this probably wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: `recognize_google` requires audio content.  How are you planning to use it without downloading the content?

Comment: @AnonCoward. I will need to download the data. I was just thinking it would be easier to process in the cloud although I will probably need to use an AWS function right?

Answer (score 1):

> 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 485: character maps to

You opened the audio file in text mode. You need to open it in binary mode.

```py
f = open('myfile.wav', 'rb')
```

Comment: Thanks. I can use that solution with files that have been downloaded but how do I convert objects/files from s3 to binary in the python script without downloading them.